# Python CSV write output error when using DictReader and DictWriter for output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a script to reformat a .CSV file. The read file starts as pipe delimited and get written as comma.

All it needs to do is index the columns and output them to file the way I want.

I am able to make it work perfectly when printing the output to screen (see two commented lines at bottom of code), but when I attempt to write to file I get the [following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfhxB.png). I have tried to change the format of `csv_writer.writerow({'F3'})` several different ways. It would seem I don't completely understand how to use `writerow()`. Or if I am completely missing something to make it function properly.

I also have to put static fields in, in front of the index fields. (i.e I need a "1" put in front of the F3 field) Is there an additional trick to that?

```
import csv

csv.register_dialect('piper', delimiter='|')

with open('pbfile.txt', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, dialect='piper',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)


with open('ouput2.csv', 'w', newline='') as new_file:
    fieldnames = ['F0','F1','F2','F3','F4','F5','F6']

    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, delimiter=',',fieldnames=fieldnames)

    for line in csv_reader:
        #csv_writer.writeheader()
        csv_writer.writerow({'F3'})
        csv_writer.writerow({'F1', 'F2', 'F6'})
        #print('1', line['F3'])
        #print('380', line['F1'], line['F2'], line['F6'])
```

Comment: What does your `output2.csv` look like? You wrote `for line in csv_reader` in the 6th line, but `csv_reader` is not initialized yet.

Comment: @HaoTan the ouput2.csv file ends up completely blank

Comment: `{'F1', 'F2', 'F6'}` is a _set_.  `writer.writerow` expects a _list_: `['F1', 'F2', 'F6']` (note the use of square rather than curly brackets).